# Missing files in ODBC folder on ubuntu

Tags: file, ubuntu, odbc, missing-data

I tried to install the ODBC driver on Ubuntu 18.04 but my directory is empty:

```
root@robos:/usr/lib/odbc# isql -v robos
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/odbc/libmyodbc.so' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

My directory is emtpy:

```
root@robos:/usr/lib/odbc# ls /usr/lib/odbc
root@robos:/usr/lib/odbc#
```

How can I install the missing files afterwards?
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Try install odbc:

```
sudo apt install odbcinst
```